# Multiple form to single action in spring with single button

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I have a single jsp where there are two spring forms are available.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="obj1" action="/some">
                here i get the list of values and show then in dropdown.
</form:form>

<form:form modelAttribute="obj2" action="/some">
                here i have some other things like table etc and **a submit button**.
</form:form>
```

Both obj1 and obj2 are model objects and get filled by two database call.

```
@RequestMapping("some")
public ModelAndView somemethod(){
   return "modelandview";
 }
```

Now, How can i retrieve the selected value in dropdown to this controller action when submit button pressed. Now, i am able to get the data from another form(for example obj2 form). Probably, I can not use form inside another form option but if that is only the option and i will go ahead and try again. a

Comment: Put everything in one form?

Comment: But their modelAttribute is different and how can i put in that case?

Comment: Bind them to the same Model object. If necessary create a wrapper round your two existing model objects and bind the individual fields to these nested properties e.g. obj1.abc, obj2.xyz

Comment: Hey, Can you point out to any example that i can look for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to each form and remove the submit button, just add an input after the forms:

```
<form:form class="formSubmit" modelAttribute="obj1" action="/some">
    here i get the list of values and show then in dropdown.
</form:form>
<form:form class="formSubmit" modelAttribute="obj2" action="/some">
    here i have some other things like table etc.
</form:form>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
```

Then add a jQuery handler to the submit button that will loop over each form and submit it

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('.formSubmit').each(function() {
        $(this).submit();
    });
});
```